# How to see conflicts after an auto merge with merge=union in git

Tags: git, merge, conflict, gitattributes

I have `*.csproj merge=union` in `.gitattributes`, and I am pretty happy about how git manages merges with that on. Other times though, git will do really poor job merging xml files, such as `*.csproj` (because of lacking a proper xml merge driver I hear) and I cannot load VS project anymore.

So I `git reset --hard HEAD^` and try again with `git merge --no-commit --no-ff` so I can sneak peak before committing the merge.

For instance:

```
mkdir foobar && cd foobar
git init
echo "README merge=union" > .gitattributes
echo "Hello" > README
git add --all
git commit -m 'Initial commit.'
git checkout -b italian-translation
echo "Ciao" > README
git commit -am 'Italian translation'
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit --no-ff italian-translation
```

At this point `README` contains:

```
Hello
Ciao
```

Then I try to see conflicting version of `README`, so I can dive into conflicts and resolve manually:

```
git checkout -m README
```

And I expect something similar to:

```
<<<
Hello
===
Ciao
>>>
```

But I still get:

```
Hello
Ciao
```

What am I missing here please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying "merge=union", the merge of the two versions of the files succeeded without a conflict, and the "successful" merge was committed to master.

There are cases where that is appropriate, but, as you're experiencing, XML is not one of them.  For XML files, you're probably best off using the default merge algorithm, which will encounter conflicts, trash your XML with "<<<<<<<<<", "=======" and ">>>>>>>" conflict markers (I didn't count, don't take those literally), mark the conflicted files in the index (details visible with "git log --merge --left-right -p"), fail the merge, do no commit, and force you to resolve the conflicts by editing the conflicted files to remove the conflict markers and "git add"ing each before it allows you to make the commit.

This is such a pain that for one flavor of XML file, I wrote a utility that translates that kind of XML file into a directory full of small text files representing the XML tree as nodes, and a counterpart that can translate the directory back into the original XML file.  Then, I tell git to ignore the original XML file and put the derived directory under version control and let the file merges occur on all the little XML tree node representations (which has only twice experienced conflicts).  My employer owns that code, or I'd put it here.  Nothing patentable, though: use a library to parse the XML and use a hash table to name the nodes and their children, and come up with a diff friendly representation of the XML nodes, including the names of their child nodes, names which also serve as file names in the directory holding all the little files representing the names.